# AWS S3 AccessDenied (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, devops

Someone provide me a KEY_ID, SECRET_KEY and BUCKET_NAME.

I try connect to S3 but Request throw an Error.

S3.js

```
require("dotenv").config()
const fs = require('fs');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const bucketName = process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET
const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_S3_KEY
const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET
const region = process.env.AWS_S3_REGION

aws.config.update({
    region,
    accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey
});

const s3 = new aws.S3()


const getBuckets = ()=> s3.listBuckets().promise()
```

Error: Connection error AccessDenied: Access Denied

Comment: Do you see connection refused or access denied?  Are you sure the access key you've been given has permission to list all buckets?

Comment: Access denied. I´ll edit the title.

Comment: It´s a technical test for backend developer. They provide me his bucket.

Comment: Ok, if they're asking you to do something with a bucket, why would the key have access to list other bucket names?

Comment: What do you mean? 
I have his Bucket name.

Comment: And never using it.  You're calling `listBuckets`, which "Returns a list of all buckets"

Comment: You´re my hero. :)